# How do you make it so you don't have to mention the user for the description discord bot

Tags: node.js, discord

```
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { stripIndents } = require("common-tags");

module.exports = {
    name: "report",
    category: "moderation",
    description: "Reports a member",
    usage: "<mention, id>",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {

        if (message.deletable) message.delete();

        let rMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);

        if (!rMember)
            return message.reply("Couldn't find that person?").then(m => m.delete(5000));

        if (rMember.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS") || rMember.user.bot)
            return message.channel.send("Can't report that member").then(m => m.delete(5000));


        if (!args[1])
            return message.channel.send("Please provide a reason for the Arrest").then(m => m.delete(5000));

        const channel = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === "arrest-log")

        if (!channel)
            return message.channel.send("Couldn't find a `#arrest-log` channel").then(m => m.delete(5000));

        const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setColor("#ff0000")
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL)
            .setAuthor("Arrest Log", rMember.user.displayAvatarURL )
            .setDescription(stripIndents`**> User:** ${rMember} 
            **> Arrested by:** ${message.member}
            **> Reason:** ${args.slice(1).join("")}`);

        return channel.send(embed);
    }
}
```

Comment: So when you do the !report they don't have to be in the server you can type their name in and it will still pop up in the embed but you don't need to @ them or mention them in any kind of way

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a few more options. Add an option to find by name, then filter the member list by the name. Also could add an option to find by ID then filter the member list by ID.

Comment: Can you please give me an example.